# Asking questions regarding shell scripting - Is this the right place?

Tags: discussion

If I'm asking questions regarding shell scripting. Where is the right place to do so? Is it Stackexchange original page or this?

Comment: welcome to U&L. As long as it is Unix/Linux, it is OK, explain your problem, what you have (starting file/command) what you want (final file) and what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine. Shell scripting is on topic and welcome on both SO and here. Which site you prefer is basically up to you.

Personally, and clearly this is a completely unbiased opinion, I would recommend you ask them here. SO gets thousands of questions per day, while we get less than 100. Your question is more likely to be noticed here.